# Can't start mysql on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql

When I try to start

```
sudo service mysql start
start: Job failed to start
```

Then I look the `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

```
160122  8:43:42 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160122  8:43:42 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160122  8:43:42 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160122  8:43:42 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160122  8:43:42 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160122  8:43:42 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
^G/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibv0Dwa6' (Errcode: 13)
160122  8:43:42  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
160122  8:43:42 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
160122  8:43:42 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
160122  8:43:42 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
160122  8:43:42 [ERROR] Aborting

160122  8:43:42 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

The permissions for `/tmp`

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Jan 22 08:39 tmp
```

I also tried

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-common
```

and to reinstall everything new.. But it didn't solve the problem.
The socket `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` exists:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

EDIT:

`/var/run/mysqld` I just saw this doesn't exist. How can I create this?

EDIT2:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

When I try to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from Phil is the solution:

/tmp should be chmod'ed to 777 – Phil 2 days ago

`sudo chmod 777 /tmp`

(I can not set a comment as answer, so maybe some mod can change my answer to his?)